# OSGi Web application Tutorial

Tags: osgi

Can anybody provide me the good tutorial link for creating OSGi web application using JBoss Developer.I have to use OSGi framework but I cant figure out where to start and I am using JBoss developer tool for that.

Comment: is it right that JBoss developer is based on eclipse?

Comment: Yes, JBoss developer is based on eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a general introduction to OSGi web applications [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2011/11/writing-an-osgi-web-application/), although it doesn't specifically discuss JBoss or JBoss developer. However, the principles are pretty universal. If you can create a normal OSGi bundle and a normal web application you can create an OSGi web application.